# Is this question about US spaces still an open problem?

Tags: gn.general-topology

In [Between $T_1$ and $T_2$](https://doi.org/10.2307/2316017), Albert Wilansky mentioned in **6.** that it was not known whether or not every locally compact US space is $T_2$.

Is this matter still an open problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it is not. S. Franklin gave an example in his [review of Wilansky's paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=208557): take a compact space with a point $x$ that is not the limit of a non-trivial sequence, for example the ordinal $\omega_1+1$ with $x=\omega_1$, and double that point. The set of our space is $\omega_1\cup\{\omega_1^a, \omega_1^b\}$; the points other than $\omega_1^a$ and $\omega_1^b$ have their normal neighbourhoods and the (basic) neigbourhoods of $\omega_1^i$ ($i=a,b$) are $(\alpha,\omega_1)\cup\{\omega_1^i\}$ with $\alpha<\omega_1$.

The result is US and (locally compact), but not Hausdorff.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have a reference for Franklin's article?

Comment: The link points to his review in Mathematical Reviews; I don't know if he published this anywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think your link and my link go to the same article, which is Wilansky's original paper. Maybe it isn't the correct URL?

Comment: Your links takes me to JSTOR (the paper), my link takes me to MathSciNet ([the review by Stan Franklin](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=208557))

Comment: Maybe I'm not used to MathSciNet, but when I click on your link a MathSciNet page pops up, and there is another link named "Article".  When you click on it, it takes you to the JSTOR article, no? I'm sorry, but I can't figure out how to access Franklin's review from your link.

Comment: You need a subscription to MathSciNet. I put a copy of the review [here](https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/~hart/temp/mr208557.pdf)

Comment: That was the issue, thank you for your patience and for the copy.